# Ifort : move_alloc() on attribute of a Pointer,intent(in) triggers error

Tags: pointers, memory-management, compiler-errors, fortran

I would like to extend an allocatable attribute of a structure and [`MOVE_ALLOC()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOVE_005fALLOC.html) seems the cleanest way to do it. So I created a routine using a `Pointer, Intent(in)` pointing to the structure as argument and tried to call:

```
Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)  :: str1
...
call MOVE_ALLOC(TO= str1%arrayofint , FROM= temparray)
```

where `str1` is the pointer to the structure and `arrayofint` is the attribute to be extended. See subroutine `LOC_extendsecond()` of the following sample code. **The compiler ifort returns the following error:**

```
Source1.f90(91): error #7999: The FROM or TO arguments of a MOVE_ALLOC reference must not be INTENT(IN).   [MOVE_ALLOC]
```

As if `str1%arrayofint` were `Intent(in)`. **Keeping in mind that the pointer `str1` is `Intent(in)`,  are the attributes of the pointed structure `str1%arrayofint` to be considered as `Intent(in)`?**

To investigate the issue, I tried not to use `MOVE_AllOC()` and found that deallocating or allocating `str1%arrayofint` in the routine does not trigger any error or warning from ifort. See subroutine `LOC_extendfirst()` of the sample code.

A workaround was suggested by a collegue of mine (thanks Luc!): a local copy of the pointer is created and `MOVE_AllOC()` can be called using this local copy of the pointer without ifort raising an error. See subroutine `LOC_extendthird()` of the sample code.

```
Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)  :: str1
Type(STRUCT1), Pointer  :: str2
str2=>str1
...
call MOVE_ALLOC(TO= str2%arrayofint , FROM= temparray)
```

Here goes the sample code:

```
Module Source1

    Implicit None

    Public :: STRUCT1

  Private

  Type STRUCT1
      Integer, dimension(:), allocatable    :: arrayofint 

  End Type STRUCT1

    Contains

    Subroutine newstruct1(str1,ier,errmsg)

        Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(inout)  :: str1
        Integer, Intent(out) :: ier
        character(len=256), Intent(out) :: errmsg

        ier=0
        allocate(str1,stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
        if( ier>0) return

        allocate(str1%arrayofint(2),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
        if( ier>0) return

    End Subroutine newstruct1

    Subroutine LOC_extendfirst(str1,targetsize,ier,errmsg)
        Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)  :: str1
        Integer, Intent(out)  :: ier
        character(len=256), Intent(out)  :: errmsg
        Integer, Intent(in)  :: targetsize 

        Integer,dimension(1) :: shp
        Integer :: newsize , formersize
        Integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: temparray

        ier=0

        shp=shape(str1%arrayofint)
        formersize=shp(1)
        if (targetsize .GT. formersize) then
            newsize=MAX(targetsize,2*formersize)
            allocate(temparray(newsize),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
            if( ier>0) then; return ; endif
            temparray(1:formersize)=str1%arrayofint
            allocate(temparray(formersize),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
            if( ier>0) then; return ; endif 
            temparray=str1%arrayofint
            if(allocated(str1%arrayofint)) deallocate(str1%arrayofint)
            allocate(str1%arrayofint(newsize),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
            if( ier>0) then; return ; endif  
            str1%arrayofint(1:formersize)=temparray
            if(allocated(temparray)) deallocate(temparray)
        endif

  End Subroutine LOC_extendfirst

      Subroutine LOC_extendsecond(str1,targetsize,ier,errmsg)
          Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)  :: str1
          Integer, Intent(out)  :: ier
          character(len=256), Intent(out)  :: errmsg
          Integer, Intent(in)  :: targetsize 

          Integer,dimension(1) :: shp
          Integer :: newsize , formersize
          Integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: temparray

          ier=0

          shp=shape(str1%arrayofint)
          formersize=shp(1)
          if (targetsize .GT. formersize) then 
               newsize=MAX(targetsize,2*formersize)
               allocate(temparray(newsize),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
               if( ier>0) then; return ; endif
               temparray(1:formersize)=str1%arrayofint
               ! TODO uncomment the following line to get error from ifort
               call MOVE_ALLOC(TO= str1%arrayofint , FROM= temparray)
          endif

  End Subroutine LOC_extendsecond

  Subroutine LOC_extendthird(str1,targetsize,ier,errmsg)
      Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)  :: str1
      Integer, Intent(out)  :: ier
      character(len=256), Intent(out)  :: errmsg
      Integer, Intent(in)  :: targetsize 

      Integer,dimension(1) :: shp
      Integer :: newsize , formersize
      Integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: temparray

      Type(STRUCT1), Pointer  :: str2
      ier=0

      str2=>str1
      shp=shape(str2%arrayofint)
      formersize=shp(1)
      if (targetsize .GT. formersize) then 
          newsize=MAX(targetsize,2*formersize)
          allocate(temparray(newsize),stat=ier, errmsg=errmsg)
          if( ier>0) then; return ; endif
          temparray(1:formersize)=str1%arrayofint
          call MOVE_ALLOC(TO= str2%arrayofint , FROM= temparray)

      endif

  End Subroutine LOC_extendthird

  End Module Source1
```

Calling ifort 19.0.2.190 IA32 on windows, using `ifort /nologo /debug:full /Od /debug-parameters:all /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source /warn:uncalled /warn:interfaces /Qsave  /traceback /check:pointer /check:bounds /check:uninit /libs:static /threads /dbglibs /c /Qm32 "Source1.f90"` produces the error.

**On the contrary, using gfortran from gcc 6.3.0 on a Debian using `gfortran -c  Source1.f90 -Wall` does not result in any error:** it only displays warnings about function not being used.

I am quite a newbie regarding Fortran. I know Fortran pointers wrap much more data than a C pointer, so I wonder whether modifying the attribute `str1%arrayofint` is correct as `str1` is a `Pointer, Intent(in)`, just like modifying str1->arrayofint in a function is correct as pointer str1 is passed by value.

How to resolve the difference of behavior between ifort and gfortran? Is ifort correct as it reports an error in the present situation? Why does ifort considers `str1%arrayofint` to be `Intent(in)`, as if `str1` were a `Type(STRUCT1), Intent(in)` and not a `Type(STRUCT1), Pointer, Intent(in)` ? Is introducing of a local copy of the pointer as shown in `LOC_extendthird()` the most appropriate way to mitigate the issue?

Comment: Gratuitous comment on your code: lines such as `if( ier>0) then; return ; endif` can be replaced by `if( ier>0) return`, ie you can have a one-liner `if` statement without either a `then` or an `end if`.

Comment: With `intent(in)` attribute you "promise" that you will only use data and not change it - see [reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-intent). Changing it to `intent(inout)` (which is the default intent attribute) should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @HighPerformanceMark for the feedback. In the original code, other routines are called before return in case of errors. Thanks @jcerar : indeed, modifying to Intent(inout) clears the issue, but the routine is called in other routines, so other routines are to be modified to Intent(inout), making the code less and less readable. Moreover, as far as I understand it, I fulfill my commitment : I do not alter the pointer `str1` as I reallocate an attribute of the pointed structure.  Given my limited experience on Fortran pointers, the previous sentence may finally prove wrong...

Comment: @jcerar, with an `intent(in)` dummy argument you are not promising not to change the data: you're only promising not to change the _pointer association_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a pointer dummy argument the `intent(in)` attribute means that the pointer shall not appear in a so-called *pointer association context*.  Loosely, this means that you aren't allowed to (potentially) change the pointer association of the dummy argument.  You are allowed the change the value of the target of this pointer.

For a pointer dummy argument the `intent(in)` attribute does not "cascade" to the subojects of the argument (such as in this case the component `arrayofint`): the component `arrayofint` of the target of `str1` does not have the `intent(in)` attribute.

In a reference like `str1%arrayofint` with `str1` a pointer, this is a reference to the component `arrayofint` of the *target* of `str1`.  Even if the `intent(in)` attribute did apply to subobjects of the pointer dummy argument the object referenced by `str1%arrayofint` is not a subobject of `str1`.

ifort is wrong to think that such an object has the `intent(in)` attribute.  You have found a valid way to work around such shortcomings in ifort.  You should consider reporting this flaw to Intel.

Finally, there may be better ways to solve your problem of resizing the component without using pointer dummy arguments, but I won't consider those in this answer.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus for your answer.  I really needed the viewpoint of an experienced fortran developer because my practice of fortran is not such that questionning the compiler correctness seems sane. Following your advice, I posted the issue on the [Intel developer zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/844283).

Comment: Please keep us updated with any conclusion from Intel.

Comment: Yes, sure! To date, the opinion of Steve Lionel is consistent with yours: there is a problem with ifort. He quotes fortran standards (8.5.10p6): `If a nonpointer object has an INTENT attribute, then all of its subobjects have the same INTENT attribute.` and `Similarly, the INTENT restrictions on pointer dummy arguments apply only to the association of the dummy argument; they do not restrict the operations allowed on its target.`.  He advises to report to the  [Online Service Center of Intel](https://supporttickets.intel.com/?lang=en-US) I'll do it and post back the conclusions.